# cividesk google sync error

Tags: wordpress, extension

I'm attempting to configure Cividesk sync for Google Apps. Running on latest installs of WP and CIVICRM.

The Cividesk screen shows that it is configured correctly.

[image]

But the log shows the following error: 
Finished execution of Cividesk sync for Google Apps with result: Failure, Error message: Google API error - either the extension is not fully configured or there is a database mismatch.

[image: Error appearing in my log]

Any suggestions on how to proceed? There is an old forum link but it simply states to re-install. Figure there might be something more current available from the stack-exchange.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The extension is configured correctly per your screenshot, so it must be an issue with the sync queue.

You can reset this queue by accessing your database (command line mysql or phpMyAdmin) and issuing the command: TRUNCATE cividesk_sync_googleapps;

The queue will be repopulated when the next sync happens.

Comment: Appreciate the response, I've gone ahead and used PHPMyAdmin to issue this command. The log shows "Finished execution of Cividesk sync for Google Apps with result: Success (Nothing needed to be synchronized.)"  I'll check in 24 hours when google's cache updates. Thanks again.

Comment: I just checked and the error continues to occur. I recently upgraded to the google app free non-profit account that provides 1000 users. Is this the version that is NOT compatible? I did read that the free version was not compatible but I was hoping it referred to the free trial (30 day) version.

Comment: The extension is compatible with the Google Apps for Nonprofits. Have you checked the Directory in your Contacts application? Are there any contacts there?

Comment: The Directory in my Contacts application shows 0 contacts. The log shows this    _Full message: 
Finished execution of Cividesk sync for Google Apps with result: Failure, Error message: Google API error - either the extension is not fully configured or there is a database mismatch.__     and once I run the TRUNCATE cividesk_sync_googleapps; in MyPHPAdmin the log shows _Parameters parsed (and passed to API method): 
a:1:{s:7:"version";i:3;}

Full message: 
Finished execution of Cividesk sync for Google Apps with result: Success (Nothing needed to be synchronized.)_     Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Are there several versions of the extension?
This version here: https://civicrm.org/extensions/google-apps-sync
seems obsolete.
Is it working with the OAuth2 of Google?

Could you guide us, Nicolas?

Regards.

```
There are obsolete help windows This option will send your registration information to Cividesk. Registering is important since it allows us to judge the level of interest for the developments we are producing, and hence plan for improvements or new developments accordingly.
```